# Component One Spell checker control (version: 2.2.20082.82) issue with apostrophies and parenthesis

Tags: vb.net, componentone

I am having an issue that I hope someone has a solution regard the Component One Spell checker control (version:  2.2.20082.82)...

I am currently using the C1.Win.C1Spell.C1Spell control on a **windows form application** written in **VB.net**.  The user will enter notes into a text box and push a button on the form that will call the .CheckControl() method and passing in the notes text box to perform a spell check on.

The users are complaining that too many things are coming up in the spell check dialog box such as:

words with an apostrophe --> member's 
words with paranthesis --->  claims(s) 
We were able to control things such as dates to not return by setting the .IgnoreWithNumbers property to be true but could not find a way to cancel out of the dialog box for the above mentioned scenarios.

I would appreciate any suggestions to try or information on any newer versions that might allow our scenarios to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You state windows forms, but use the asp.net tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a 2 years old binary, ComponentOne has an really great community/product support and release fixes regularly so the chances that your problem is fixed now is really high.

Also, check their online forum for that component: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/CS/Visual_Studio_Extensions_20/f/83.aspx

Check here for latest/next release, for this component there was a release 10 dec 2010:
http://prerelease.componentone.com/

Comment: yeah we did that (downloaded the next release) but it was for the newer version.  So we have to upgrade.  I was hoping to not have to do that...